# Bidirectional async Java RPC

Tags: java, asynchronous, rpc, protocol-buffers

[protobuf-rpc-pro](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-rpc-pro/) provides a bidirectional async RPC implementation for Java based on Protocol Buffers. Are there other like this (Protocol Buffers not necessary)? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293011/asynchronous-bidirectional-rpc) is similar, but received only replies about Python.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's wrong with protocol buffers?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Nothing, and my fallback plan is to simply use PB as replacement for our homegrown serialization library, and send messages/listen for replies using Mina, as we do currently. But PB doesn't provide an RPC implementation by itself.

Comment: That is to say, I'm still not seeing why protobufs + protobuf-rpc-pro like you've suggested doesn't address your needs.  Meh.

Comment: @LouisWasserman It well may, I'll certainly try it out. Just asked the question in case there are significantly better alternatives which I am unaware of (as I was of this one until today).

Answer (score 1):

Similar to one of the python based answers in the question you linked, there is also a Versile Platform implementation for java called [Versile Java](http://versile.com/products/vjava/) (full disclosure: I am one of the developers). It is AGPL licensed and currently in development; if that works for your project you might want to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Protobuf wiki lists some RPC implementations - see http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns#RPC_Implementations
(just in case if you didn't see it)

Comment: I did, that's where I found protobuf-rpc-pro.